# Range based for loop doesn't work with pointer even when begin()/end() defined for it?

Tags: c++11, for-loop

According to range based for loop documentation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

> *`begin_expr`* and *`end_expr`* are defined as follows:
>
> - If range_expression is an expression of array type, then *`begin_expr`* is `__range` and *`end_expr`* is `(__range + __bound)`, where `__bound` is the number of elements in the array (if the array has unknown size or is of an incomplete type, the program is ill-formed)
> - If `range_expression` is an expression of a class type `C` that has a member named `begin` and/or a member named `end` (regardless of the type or accessibility of such member), then *`begin_expr`* is `__range.begin`) and *`end_expr`* is `__range.end()`;
> - Otherwise, *`begin_expr`* is `begin(__range)` and *`end_expr`* is `end(__range)`, which are found via [argument-dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) (non-ADL lookup is not performed).

However, if I define `begin()` and `end()` for a pointer type, it fails to work.

## Example

```
#include <iostream>

using LPCSTR = char const*;

LPCSTR begin(LPCSTR str)
{
    return str;
}

LPCSTR end(LPCSTR str)
{
    return str + strlen(str);
}

int main()
{
    LPCSTR text = "Hello, world!\n";
    for (auto c : text)
    {
        std::cout << c;
    }
}
```

Error(s):

```
source_file.cpp:18:17: error: invalid range expression of type 'const char *'; no viable 'begin' function available
    for (auto c : text)
                ^ ~~~~
1 error generated.
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://rextester.com/BXK17523)

I don't see any reference that pointers are excluded from the ADL, so what reason would there be as to why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **[basic.lookup.argdep]/2**  For each argument type `T` in the function call, there is a set of zero or more associated namespaces and a
>   set of zero or more associated classes to be considered...
>
> (2.1) — If `T` is a fundamental type, its associated sets of namespaces and classes are both empty...
>
> (2.4) — If `T` is a pointer to `U` or an array of `U`, its associated namespaces and classes are those associated with `U`...

From these, a set of namespaces asscociated with `char const*` is empty, so there's nothing for ADL to look at.

Comment: Hmm. Good to know.

Comment: Do you know if there was any motivation for that or is it just because that is how they defined it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this part:

> non-ADL lookup is not performed

`begin` and `end` in this context would be found by non-ADL lookup, rather than ADL since pointers aren't "defined in the global namespace".